# Conditional Query & Pagination in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pagination, laravel-7

**$vistors** will return all data from `vistors` table

I'm hoping to query all visitors if `$visitor->ip != '127.0.0.1'` when `$inputs['hideMe'] == true` requested from the client-side.

## View

```
http://app.test/visitor?interval=day
```

[image]

## Route

```
Route::get('/visitor','VisitorController@index');
```

## I have

```
public function index()
{
    $inputs    = Request::all();
    $interval  = '';

    if(array_key_exists('interval', $inputs)){
        $interval  = $inputs['interval'];
    }

    switch ($interval) {
        case 'day':
        $data = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->today())->paginate(15);
        break;
        case 'week':
        $data = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subWeek())->paginate(15);
        break;
        case 'month':
        $data = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subMonth())->paginate(15);
        break;
        case 'year':
        $data = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subYear())->paginate(15);
        break;
        default:
        $data = Visitor::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);
        break;
    }




    $visitors = [];
    function hideMe($inputs, $data){

        foreach($data as $i => $visitor){
            if($visitor->ip != '127.0.0.1' || $visitor->ip != '24.62.137.111'){
                $visitors[$i] = $visitor;
            }

        }

    }

    if(array_key_exists('hideMe', $inputs)){
        $hideMe  = $inputs['hideMe'];
        if($hideMe == true){
            hideMe($inputs, $data);
        }
    } else {
        $visitors = $data;
    }


    // dd($visitors);


    return View::make('layouts.be.visitors.index', get_defined_vars());
}
```

When I did that, it does not seem to work.
Since I use paginate on my view, I will get this error all the time.

> Call to a member function withQueryString() on array

## Result

This is working perfectly

- ✅ `http://app.test/visitor?interval=day`
- ✅ `http://app.test/visitor?interval=week`
- ✅ `http://app.test/visitor?interval=month`
- ✅ `http://app.test/visitor?interval=year`

This is not working at all

- ❌ `http://app.test/visitor?interval=week&hideMe=true`

**Any suggestions on how to add logic to my query?**

Comment: What's the routing to get to the method?

Comment: I added the route `Route::get('/visitor','VisitorController@index');`

Comment: Can you show how the index method is initialized?  IE how do you get the `$inputs` variable into the`hideme()` method?  Is this within `index()`?

Comment: I'll just share my entire `index()` of my `VisitorController` that load that view.

Comment: Are you getting the $hideMe param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `$visitor` is an `array` if `hideMe()` is triggered, otherwise, it's a [`LengthAwarePaginator`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html). [`withQueryString`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.html#method_withQueryString) is a method of `AbstractPaginator`. So of course you won't be able to use `$visitors->withQueryString()` if `$visitor` is just a native PHP `array`.

The solution here is to filter out rows with IP `'127.0.0.1'` and `'24.62.137.111'` during the query building stage. Like so:

```php
    switch ($interval) {
        case 'day':
        $q = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->today());
        break;
        case 'week':
        $q = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subWeek());
        break;
        case 'month':
        $q = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subMonth());
        break;
        case 'year':
        $q = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subYear());
        break;
        default:
        $q = Visitor::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
        break;
    }

    if ($inputs['hideMe']) {
        $q = $q->whereNotIn('ip', ['127.0.0.1', '24.62.137.111']);
    }

    $data = $q->paginate(15);
```

I haven't tested my code, but you get the idea.

P.S. Just a rule of thumb, always use `Collection`s in Laravel instead of PHP arrays, unless for method parameters if you want to easily unit test them.

Comment: @cyber8200 hmm... I'm not sure based on the information I know currently. But if you think you have another problem relating to your query instead of how to paginate the query results, perhaps ask another question and include the query and some example data containing rows that shouldn't be in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you were trying to do with the `$inputs` variable.  It might be easier to load the info in in a more conventional Laravel route / controller collection based path.

Try adding the route with the params:

```
Route::get('/visitor/{interval}/{hideMe}','VisitorController@index');
```

Then on the index:

```
public function index($interval, $hideMe){}
```

Alternately, if you don't want to do this, you might find some relief using the `request()` helper directly to use a collection instead of passing to a new array variable, inside the `index` method rather than another function inside that method:

```
 $hideMe  = request()->input('hideMe');
```

Comment: Are you sure that was the answer ?

Comment: Yes, it is part of it for sure.  It is a cleaner method than having a function inside a function.  Using the helper directly also facilitates.  Then, using a whereIn() query as Daniel suggests, it will work.  You've got a couple of issues underneath to improve before getting to the query, which is what I am recommending above.